# How can i call a child property function using Apache Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, mozilla, rhino

If i have a js object such as below stored in a js file

```
var _sampleProcessor = {
    process: function(data){
        ...
    }

}
```

How would i use Apache Rhino to call the process function?

```
// sb holds the contents of the js file
Context cx = Context.enter();
Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
cx.evaluateString(scope, sb.toString(), "Test", 1, null);

Object processor = scope.get("sampleProcessor ", scope);
if (processor  == Scriptable.NOT_FOUND) {
    System.out.println("processor  is not defined.");
}
```

Getting to the root of the object is easy, but how do i traverse the object tree to get at the process function property

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample does a few things. Pulls out the `sampleProcessor` as your example does, and also pulls out the `process` property and executes that function.

It also shows adding Java objects into the scope so they can be used - the `System.out` object in the example.

```
package grimbo.test.rhino;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;

public class InvokeFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sb = "var sampleProcessor = {\n" + "    process: function(data){\n    out.println(0); return 1+1;\n    }\n" + "}";

        Context cx = Context.enter();
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

        Object out = Context.javaToJS(System.out, scope);
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "out", out);

        cx.evaluateString(scope, sb.toString(), "Test", 1, null);

        // get the sampleProcessor object as a Scriptable
        Scriptable processor = (Scriptable) scope.get("sampleProcessor", scope);
        System.out.println(processor);

        // get the process function as a Function object
        Function processFunction = (Function) processor.get("process", processor);
        System.out.println(processFunction);

        // execute the process function
        Object ob = cx.evaluateString(scope, "sampleProcessor.process()", "Execute process", 1, null);
        System.out.println(ob);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[object Object]
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.Test_1@b169f8
0.0
2
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks so much for the help, your example is exactly what i was looking for